# assembly illegal instruction ".model small"

Tags: assembly, dos, assembly-resolution, fasm

my code :

```
.MODEL SMALL
.CODE
ORG 100H

Label1 : JMP Label2
+---------------------+
| TEMPAT DATA PROGRAM |
+---------------------+

Label2 :
+---------------------+
| TEMPAT   PROGRAM    |
+---------------------+
 INT 20H
 END     Label1
```

but I get error "Ilegal Instruction" and "Instruction = MODEL.SMALL"
I use flat assembler 1.71.21

Please HELP! I am newbie for assembly

Answer (score 3):

This looks like MASM (Microsoft Assembler) syntax. FASM (Flat Assembler) needs different directives.

MSDOS-`.COM`-programs:

```
ORG 100H

Label1 : JMP Label2

;+---------------------+ | TEMPAT DATA PROGRAM | +---------------------+

Label2 :

;+---------------------+ | TEMPAT PROGRAM | +---------------------+

INT 20H
```

Only `ORG 100` and the code, nothing else

---

MSDOS-`.EXE`-programs:

```
format MZ
entry cseg:main

segment dseg
; no data

segment cseg
main:

Label1 : JMP Label2

;+---------------------+ | TEMPAT DATA PROGRAM | +---------------------+

Label2 :

;+---------------------+ | TEMPAT PROGRAM | +---------------------+

INT 20H
```

At least no `ORG 100H`, no `END`. Did you read the manual: http://flatassembler.net/docs.php?article=manual#2.4?